# How to deploy a react + vite app to a private hosting with cpanel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cpanel, web-deployment, vite

Im currently learning web dev so I wrote a tasklist app using React + Vite in VSCode.
You can see it here: https://github.com/AdSaMo/react-tasklist

In Vite's documentation you can find several ways to deploy an app (Git-hub pages, Netlify, etc...) but that's not what I was looking for.

The problem comes when I want to deploy it in a private shared hosting. I've got a domain and a hosting in Sered and I would like to deploy it there. I have seen some posts talking about pasting everything inside build folder in to the public_html folder via cpanel.

However, as I'am using Vite when I run "npm run buld" I don't get a "build" folder but a "dist" one.

I am not sure but I guess structure is different, so when I include what's inside of dist folder into public_html and I type the URL in my browser nothing shows up. Just a white screen with some errors in console:

[What shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78A2c.png)

When that's what it should be like:
https://adsamo.github.io/react-tasklist/

Anyone knows how could I have this app with dist folder instead of build folder in my domain and hosting via cpanel?

Thanks all!

PD: Im pretty new, so pls have mercy xD

Comment: just build it and upload it

Comment: Where do I upload It (which folder)? As far as I know It is already built.

Comment: in the root of cpanel

Comment: Not working for me. I'm getting shown errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it. I just had to upload it normally via cPanel.
The problem was that href was wrong (wrong path) in index.html

Answer (score 0):

remove "/" from src or href attributes of links in the index.html file
for example

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="vite.svg" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Vite + React</title>
  <script type="module" crossorigin src="assets/index-41c685df.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/index-afab32f6.css">
</head>
```